What is the historical origin of lone CR as a line terminator?
There are two main approaches to line terminators today:

CR+LF: Windows, also the Internet standard. Windows got it from DOS, which got it from CP/M, which got it from DEC operating systems. It goes back to how teletypes required both characters to advance to the next line.
bare LF: popularised by Unix, but Unix got it from Multics, where it appears to have originated as a simplification of CR+LF. Multics continued to send CR+LF to terminals, but LF ⇒ CR+LF translation was performed in the terminal driver, an approach continued by Unix systems today.

However, historically, there has been a third convention, once widespread, but now rare: bare CR. It was very common on 8-bit computer systems, including Commodore 64, Acorn BBC, Apple IIs, TRS-80 and ZX Spectrum. It was also the standard convention on classic Mac OS, which inherited it from Apple IIs. And it also saw use by various other systems, including Oberon and MIT Lisp Machines.
There are also various other conventions which saw some use other than these major three – e.g. EBCDIC NEL character (also present in ISO 8859, ISO 2022, and Unicode as a C1 control), LF+CR (spooled text on Acorn BBC and RISC OS), RS (ASCII record separator, early versions of QNX), not using line terminators at all (e.g. fixed length records, or length-prefixed variable length records—common on mainframe and minicomputer platforms, including IBM mainframes, AS/400, RMS under OpenVMS and before that RSX-11).
But I want to focus this question on the bare CR convention in particular: where did it originate? We know the bare LF convention started on Multics and spread from there; but where did the bare CR convention come from? Does anyone know the first system to have used it? Why did people pick bare CR instead of bare LF?

For 8 bit systems it was not really about copying a first but practical application - and part of the common theme of reinventing the wheel. Unix and others moved from physical control (CR+LF) to logical (LF) by employing device drivers to handle any mapping. Micros (re)started development without device drivers, without a driver translating a CR send by ENTER but giving it right to application. Terminals (and printers) could be configured to treat CR (or LF) as CR+LF, making use of CR the most simple way in and out. Once early micros had established this, the rest was copying/following.

You missed one major approach to line terminators, and that is to not actually have them in file systems. You can see this approach, for example, in systems that began with card input. Why invent a 'line terminator' character you don't need?

The Multics line terminator was called 'newline' and was represented by 012. It specifically moved the print position to the first column of the next line. On devices that did not have a 'newline' it could be sent as carriage return, line feed. But internally it was a 'newline' character. The point may be obscure if you have only used systems where the internal code and all device codes are identical, but this has not always been true. Newline is a natural choice if you have newline-capable devices; it occurred organically on more than one system.

What did EBCDIC systems use?

I knew all that stuff about mainframes, EBCDIC, etc, but I left it out of the question for sake of brevity. However, since people are bringing it up I added mention of it. Still, want to focus here on the bare CR convention, not what mainframes/etc did

Isn't the choice of a line-ending character a relatively arbitrary one? (Except for the Sinclair ZX81, where it had to be $76, for reasons - and nobody cared). Especially for home computers, that were unlikely to ever come in contact with professional IT or TTYs, the choice was obviously 50:50 between LF and CR, the obvious candidates. Sinclair did, BTW, unlike the ZX Spectrum, use LF on the QL, because that targeted the "professional market".

@hippietrail If EBCDIC is meant to mean/360ish mainframes, line length in next to all handling was done by length termination, either fixed (think 80 char punch cards or tape blocks),or variable with a preceding length (usually halfwords). the only somewhat common use case for a line terminator was teletypes and non formatted terminal output. For such it was neither CR (x'0D') not LF (x'25') but 'logical new line' NL (x'15').

Acknowledge that it goes all the way back to the typewriter (Manual). Carriage Return and Line Feed were both accomplished by the handle. First the CR and the LF. The LF when the carriage hit the end.

It's not just 'mainframes' and 'ebcdic'.  Counted records, no stored terminators, were standard on many DEC PDP-11 systems and on VMS. All minicomputers with ASCII character set.

My overall point is, you are trying to establish "the first" to store just CR, as if there's a line of succession, for what I see as a local choice, organically made.  Even if there is a first, chronologically speaking, it does not follow that others "copied" the convention, whatever the convention is (CR, NL, CR-LF, count).

PDP-11 Unix (1st ed) used newline as line terminator.
It by default expected terminals to treat 012 as newline, being biased to model 37 teletypes which apparently had that as an option. See the special files man section, files tty0 to tty5. However, newline could be simulated on output by CR/LF, and CR on input could be converted to 012.  So is CR a line terminator?

One of the "various other conventions" for the end-of-line character was ATASCII's \x9B.  I don't know why they chose that particular code.

@DogBoy37 Concerning an old manual typewriter: I recall having the ability to perform 1) a line-feed/carriage return together (the line feed physically happened first), 2) A line feed only (usually followed by a regular line-feed/carriage return to skip multiple lines), 3) a carriage return only (to over print the line).  Although CR/LF was what a typist usually wanted, I could see the desire for a single code in computers to end-a-line in the byte cost a $ days.

The most usual terminals used to label the key that was used to terminate a line Carriage Return, by analogy to the older manual typing machines where you manually used a small lever to bring the carriage holding the paper sheet back to its initial position. So using the CR character to terminate a line should have been a natural solution. IMHO the good question is instead why on earth Multics engineers decided  to use a different character (the Line Feed one) to register an end of line...

@SergeBallesta: the standard explanation for that is that using CR as newline on output makes overprinting harder on hardcopy terminals and impact printers. You can still do it using backspace, but using CR to go straight to the start of the line and then printing a modified version was easier. Whereas, most early 8-bit micros had video displays where that wasn’t as big of an issue; early CP/M systems were used with hardcopy terminals, and notably CP/M (and its spiritual descendants including DOS/Windows/OS/2) stuck with the full CR+LF

CR-Only is an Equivalent But Independent Solution
It's easy to assume everything has a lineage of being directly related/developed in knowledge/copied, but real-world progress includes independent rediscovery/reinvention, like Columbus' re-discovery of America half a millennium after the Vikings, or Gerald Rosenberger's 1957 patent for the 'first' usable carry-look-ahead circuit a good 20 years after Zuse had already built a working mechanical computer using one. None of these are lesser discoveries because they have not been the absolute first.
In engineering (CS) it's often about different groups, often at different times (*1), having to find a solution to the same, usually well known (*2) problem. within their own/new environment. Here it's the discrepancy between wanted logical line/record handling and needed physical device handling, or the lack thereof if one had absolute control over (hardware) environment involved. In either situation, the designer may arrive at the same solution as previous systems without being influenced at all.
Gen 0: Unit Record Equipment
Data processing begins without any line terminator. Lines were cards and cards were lines. If more lines were to be printed, cards would be inserted or special conditions were wired for direct control of line and formfeed.
Gen 1: Mainframes
Mainframes stayed line-orientated, but for the (rather rare) case of in-band line handling (*3) it was done by introducing some dedicated logical line terminator, independent of physical control characters. Nicely compiled with the new, all-encompassing 8-bit EBCDIC character set. It featured the physical

CR (at x'0D') and
LF (at x'25') plus a
logical new line, NL, at x'15'.

Software with a need to handle multiple lines in a single block (*4) and outside of raw device handling would use NL to separate those lines. Still, the most common use case was line-length blocks with a format specifier at position 1.
Gen 2: The Minis
Upcoming mini computer system started from scratch. Like the very first computers their purpose was at first to provide some processing at all. Except where mainframes inherited the record-based handling as primary I/O, they restarted at character-based. As close to hardware as possible, but without the luxury of tailoring devices connected to their need, as IBM could do. They had to fit with the lowest common denominator. For I/O this meant CR/LF for TTY and TTY-derived printers. With that it was just natural to also use CR/LF.
Gen 2.5: Multics and Unix
The *ixes developed from there with a clear intention to make things better. Except, they didn't have the luxury IBM had in inventing a complete new 8-bit charset but (had to) stay within the 7 bits ASCII provided. Using any of the weakly defined ones (*5) would have prohibited certain assumed applications(*6). So either CR or LF was it and LF won.
Using LF as logical line separator makes a lot of sense. A driver could deliver (almost) the same versatility as direct output:

Logical New Line: LF will be translated to CR/LF
'physical' CR/LF: Turned into CR/LF/CR, virtually identical to CR/LF
'trickster' CR: Is passed through to allow double printing, underlining, strike-through, etc.

Minimal impact while still switching from physical to logical line control. By also adding input translation of CR to LF (and suppression of single LF), one gets 'cooked' input using just logical line markers. Beautiful new world.
Gen 3: Early Micros
Early micros restarted from scratch. While lessons learned with 2.5 were available, they started out with the very same issue as Gen 2 minis: limited resources and glad to work at all. So naturally the same solutions applied here - even more as the engineers creating those first micros and their operating systems were already using (DEC-like) mini computers before or during design.
CP/M, DOS and Windows followed that for upward compatibility ... and ultimately the Web.
Gen 3.5: Home Computer
Home computers were in a position much like the *nixes as the technology was established, but they had to make their own thing. Partly due to limited resources, but more so because they again had a close control over hardware, much more related to the situation IBM had then DEC or *nix. Their developers did not have to bother how terminals worked as they built them themselves. It's a, if not the  main feature about home computers that keyboard input and video (display) output is integrated.
They did not have need to think much about third party peripherals. Quite the other way, as those companies were keen on selling everything on their own, using lock-in as an advantage, as if an IBM sales manager had written the requirements (*7).
Example: the Apple II and its Monitor
The Apple II makes a prime example for that situation and solution chosen. Not just because it's an early home computer and was developed in-house without any external goals/restrictions (*8), but also due to being mostly developed by a single engineer.
With built-in display hardware there is no need to differentiate CR/LF at all. In fact, while the Monitor ROM's (*9) screen handling (*10) includes two entry points for CR (returning to column 0) and LF (advancing one line), CR ($FC62) always overflows into LF ($FC66), so CR alone wasn't ever possible and LF never needed. In fact, CR/LF would have resulted in advancing for two lines. CR (and LF) was directly called by COUT1 when a CR was detected. This nicely mirrors the input situation, where any line input using GETLN ($FD6A) was terminated by a single CR (not included in input length).
Either of those worked via default entry points COUT/KEYIN used by most applications including BASIC. Either used a vector which would be rerouted if other devices (printer, serial, etc.) are to be used for I/O including DOS (*11).
As a result Apple II programs would only use a CR for line, never CR/LF, and see only a CR if read on a single char basis. Since DOS hooked those output vectors, any line termination (from BASIC or otherwise) was straightforwardly stored as CR (*12) to record separator. Likewise reading from disk returned the record without trailing CR. As a result the Apple II provided the same comfort of a logical line end as *nixes did, except using CR instead of LF.
For other home computers, the reasoning (single line terminator) and constrictions (screen doesn't need two chars and keyboard delivers CR by default) can be assumed to be similar, leading to the same result.
Oh, and yes, the Mac inherited CR from the Apple II. It wasn't until OSX transplanted it onto a *nix base that LF became the default ... and many files still containing CR terminated lines :))
Conclusion
History doesn't repeat, but similar stages do require similar solutions which may end up different, in good part due the control creators had over their environment.
All strived for single character logical line termination, but

only IBM controlled peripheral design and code set,
most others controlled neither and had to go without
home computer in turn did not control charset (*13) but peripherals (*14)

As result

LF was a conscious decision to use a single char with the least impact on existing hardware, while
CR did the same yielding the least implementation effort while all-new hardware being developed anyway.


*1 - In some way also a bit like every generation thinks they are the first to invent something different that will forever be the most radical version, no matter whether art, literature or music ... anyone remember feeling shocked how rad Mozart is? :))
*2 - Already Babbage knew that improved carry handling would be of great benefit, he just couldn't come up with a working solution. The issue was widely discussed and tinkered at in the heydays of mechanical calculators (1910s to 1940s) but without much practical result.
*3 - Well, that is after those became sufficient to handle abstraction in software and the need did arise due to devices like screen based terminals.
*4 - Mainframes and their software inherited their line orientation from Unit Record Machinery. They handle a line at a time. The vast majority of I/O data was block orientated, either fixed length (punch card, fixed length file) or variable length, where each line/block was prefixed by a (usually) 16-bit length. Handling was usually single line/block.
If a device allowed line control, it was done by special fields (aka the first character of a line to be printed). This includes terminal output.
The only exception were certain non (or simple) format output modes sending multiple lines in one operation. Only here NL was used for both directions and inserted/replaced by whatever the device used/delivered.
*5 - Like the Device Control or Separator characters.
*6 - As communication and maybe more important data exchange with mainframes using them. Not to mention that the DCs were already used by some hardware, like XON/XOFF being defined by TTYs.
*7 - To be fair, they also had a situation similar to IBM, as there wasn't much third party equipment available to buy at the time they introduced their new systems - at least not much in a price range the intended customer would be able to afford ... and custom interfaces were helping to keep it that way.
*8 - Except for ASCII keyboard and NTSC output
*9 - Kind of Apple II's BIOS, a least for all built-in components.
*10 - A lovely piece of code, even more on the Autostart. Nice and tidy. Though, might need some time to read through :))
*11 - DOS is a more complex issue, as it also used those to hook itself to work at all, but for the issue of CR those quirks don't matter.
*12 - Well, it was $8D as all characters output had the high bit set, but that's also a different issue, not changing the principle of operation.
*13 - They did make up their own 8-bit extensions, but stayed with basic 7-bit ASCII for line control.
*14 - Later, when standard printers emerged during he 1980s, they featured ways to be configured to fit various machines definitions - usually including at least a basic CR->CRLF handling.

"the Monitor ROM's (*9) screen handling (*10) includes two entry points for CR (returning to column 0) and LF (advancing one line), CR ($FC62) always overflows into LF ($FC66), so CR alone wasn't possible and LF never needed" => this reminds me of the (rather similar) explanation of why Acorn outputs LF+CR instead of the more usual CR+LF – https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29939/17803 – interpretations of control characters being influenced by whatever makes the ROM IO code the smallest

@SimonKissane Oh, yes. That's another great point supporting the "related but independent" issue. Thanks. Then again, I wouldn't want to state in any way that Woz was less keen on saving space.

Early glass TTY designs (including the Apple I) kept track of cursor position using a shift register that held one bit per character position saying, essentially, "is the cursor here", and thus had no means of resetting the cursor to the start of a line.  Having glass teletypes treat CR as newline and ignore LF was easier than any other approach, and given the limited height of glass TTYs, treating CR+LF+LF as a single newline was in many cases more useful than having it advance twice.

I suspect strongly that the Apple II's use of a bare CR as its line separator was motivated by the fact that the Apple I hardware had been designed that way.

Using a bare CR as a line terminator is not equivalent but deficient because it does not allow to indicate overprinting for bolding/underlining in files destined to be printed, nor to draw progress indicators like -<cr>\<cr>|<cr>/<cr>-<cr>.... when outputting to a terminal. The same spilling from one character code to another could have been done from LF to CR.

@LeoB.Not sure what your comment is about/directed at, please elaborate. (For that kind of 'rotating' indicator using BS equivalent or  even better as now being position independent.)

@LeoB.: You could still do overprinting using backspaces.

@dan04 True, but that becomes inconvenient. With the LF terminator, maing a printed line bold is simply "string"CR"string", making it underlined similar, replacing every non-blank character with _ for the second pass, etc.

@Raffzahn If a progress indocator includes some variable-length text, line Processing <pathname>...<rotating indicator> using backspaces becomes cumbersome when switching from one file to another. In general, the need to easily return to the beginning of the current line by itself (the original meaning of CR) is more common than the need to go to the next line keeping the current position (the original meaning of LF), thus repurposing CR as "newline" is less practical.

@LeoB. I still see use of BS as the better UX (and not cumbersome). It puts the indicator where the eyes are, behind the name, not some other place way apart. Anyway, this example is missing the point the question asks: Why did different platforms reach different solutions for the end of line/record handling, not what nifty hardware specific tricks could be done with a glass tty setup. A trick failing big with a real TTY connected, wouldn't it? Nothing system design should do. Also, few home computer users would even start to think about positioning with CR  or BS. They got better.

@Raffzahn Weren't home computers used as remote terminals to connect to BBSes, if not mainframes?

@LeoB. True, some application was being a BBS client following their own protocol. Mainframe do not use CR/LF but order codes. Main point to the question, why HC do use is them not being designed with terminal operation/emulation in mind (like the DEC..DOS line of development). When used as terminals, HC had to run a terminal software, which in turn implemented whatever CR/LF/BS handling that BBS required. You might remember even the most primitive ones having quite a lot of configuration options for that. That software in turn used whatever build in/advanced methods its HC offered.

@Raffzahn: “Mainframe do not use CR/LF but order codes”: true in general but TSO line mode was a thing (and I’ve actually used it, with MVS 3.8J under Hercules). Of course that would natively be using EBCDIC NEL. But what line terminator did it use with ASCII mode peripherals, which definitely were supported? Given it did support teletypes, I must assume CRLF

The earliest mainframes used an off the shelf  mechanical TTY as a console, and these required CR LF. When later glass TTYs were used they normally emulated the physical device. When screens where used directly although strictly speaking CR and LF have a different meaning, only one of them was logically needed and it was a toss-up which one. Since Multics chose LF, and its descendant Linux won the OS arena, LF it was.

@SimonKissane Any user side and most OS side software will use NL. only special low level sections handling line output will convert them to whatever a connected device needs. More often than not this conversion will not even happen on the mainframe but a secondary communication system or some line buffer.

@JonathanRosenne Not really. ''Earliest" mainframes didn't feature text based consoles at all. If at all, those were output devices for protocol usage.

@Raffzahn I had used a number of mainframes in the early 60's including Philco 2000 and they definitely used commercial TTYs as consoles. The console also contained various switches and lights.

@JonathanRosenne Sure, except that "early 60's" is not "early Mainframe". I'd count  Philco 2000 at best as second generation (if not counting pre-tube and early one-off tube systems). Next. the 2000 was intended o work without without any TTY - it had still had not only a full panel, but even a special desk :) Last, did't the 2000 offload all I/O via tape? That would mark the connected TTY in addition to special device, so not in tradition of any terminal. OI might be wrong, as I never personally operated a Philco 2000 - they were kind of rare even back then :)))

@Raffzahn The panel could be used to control the computer, but it also had an operating system, and it used the TTY (actually a Flexowriter) for standard input and output. The one I used has 80 column punched cards for external I/O, job control and data.

Albeit not mentioned in Wikipedia, among the systems employing bare CR as the line terminator, there was Xerox Alto (as evidenced by observing the raw format of any of the files on the Alto tapes, for example, a directory, which displays in Unix as
[Indigo]<AltoTape>DDTape-Rev-A.dm!1 18 Dec 80 14:49:04 PST  T10029P T10029B^M[Indigo]<AltoTape>DDTape-Rev-A....

(note the ^M denoting the CR character)
Both Niklaus Wirth, the author of the Oberon system, known to employ CR,  and Steve Jobs were familiar with Xerox Alto.

It seems unlikely that the MIT Lisp Machine would have historically influenced its adoption by Apple II, Commodore 64, etc

@SimonKissane You're right. The Wikipedia table has an omission. Please see the updated answer.

Except that Oberon was developed way later than the common use of CR started, Apple 1 & II already used CR before Jobs visited PARC not to mention that  Jobs was no engineer involved in any low level development.

I suspect, but cannot prove, that the early Apple machines were trying to save space, so used a single character, and used CR as simply what came from the ENTER key.

Having written code on systems that stored two characters, I say one character is a superior choice, since it saves nit-picking programmers (guilty as charged) from angst about the semantics of seeing just one of the pair!

"Niklaus Wirth, the author of the Oberon system". This may be too much. That would be "the team around Niklaus Wirth and Jürg Gutknecht", including the team at ETHZ to build the Ceres hardware (a pretty cool little box). I have worked with the system but never noticed that its line termination convention was CR. I possibly vaguely remember that it was indeed CR+LF. Source?

@DavidTonhofer Source? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation mentions Oberon among the CR camp.

@dave True, but using CR as a line terminator is a poor choice because, for example, it does not allow drawing animated progress indicators like -<cr>\<cr>|<cr>/<cr>-<cr>....

Well, that's another point in its favour, then.

Originally, you entered CR on a teletype, and the carriage could take slightly more than one character time to go home from column 80. So the next command sent was a non printing character the Line Feed to move the paper up.
So an early system would respond to the user hitting CR by echoing it and then sending a LF.
Otherwise the result could be the first character of the next line smeared across the paper somewhere to the right of column 0.
My first printer was a broken Teletype ASR33 bought for £0.50. And on the way to perfect functioning, it did precisely this-there was a dashpot with a variable damping flap to get the carriage return to smartly go home without bouncing or lagging. It also somewhat stopped the table rocking sideways as the massive carriage hit home...

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
